# converting an IP address to host name

Tags: java, network-programming

In my java application if user enters the IP we need to display the host name, if host name is given then we need to display the IP of the host.

For example if user enters an IP address like `173.194.36.37` application should display `google.com` and vice verse.

Are there any utilities available to perform this operation?

Comment: you know that an IP number may have several hostnames? for example 127.0.0.1 has *both* localhost and localhost.localdomain

Comment: @vidstige Not with reverse DNS. Here the IP is mapped to exactly one host name, the so-called "canonical host name".

Comment: you can not get unique result see http://aruljohn.com/ip2hostname.html for 173.194.36.37 see bom04s02-in-f5.1e100.net not google.com!

Comment: `173.194.36.37` does not resolve to `google.com` but to `bom04s02-in-f5.1e100.net`. The IP block is owned by Google, though.

Comment: @SjB You get `bom04s02-in-f5.1e100.net`, right. And only that. Multiple names can point to one IP address, of course. But an IP address can reverse-resolve to only one host name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are coding in Java, try using [`InetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("173.194.36.37");
String host = addr.getHostName();
System.out.println(host);
```

Comment: Obviously, don't forget exception handling for UnknownHostException.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is something called [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).  [This project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnsjava/) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: No need to bring in third party libraries if there's `InetAddress.getHostName()`.

Comment: @PhilippReichart The question says "Are there any utilities available", so I think why not open-source third party libraries.

Comment: @PrakashK Simplicity. Why bring in *over 100* classes when all you want can be achieved by calling an existing method? Much less moving parts, much less to go wrong.

Comment: @PhilippReichart The InetAddress class will only get you the host name of the server, it won't get you the domain, which is what the OP was asking (although he didn't phrase it too well).

Comment: @Jon You do realize the naked domain is just one `substring()` away from any host name? That hardly requires a library.

Comment: @Philipp Reichart Running some of the InetCode on a Google server IP, I get "bom04s02-in-f5.1e100.net" for the host name. Where is the Google domain name in that?

Comment: We're talking about different things here. The DNS records for the IP address `173.194.36.37` do not mention Google at all. The only way Google is related to that IP address is *ownership*, which is unrelated to DNS and cannot be answered by DNS. Ownership of domain names and IP addresses is queried via the WHOIS protocol. AFAICT dnsjava doesn't support WHOIS, so there's no way it's capable to get "the Google domain" from the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

The project SomeKittens referred to you looks like a complete DNS server written in Java, which might be more than you need. Have a look at [`java.net.InetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html):

```
java.net.InetAddress.getByName("example.com").getHostAddress();
```

Comment: For Google.com this code gives me "74.125.237.100" as the result.

Comment: And this is correct, right?  If I go to http://74.125.237.100/ I end up at google.com.

Comment: No. The OP asked for something that would give you the domain name given an IP address. The code above gives the complete reverse - an IP address given a domain name.

Comment: He asked for "and vice verse" ...  but if you were expecting my code fragment to give you a name for an IP, why did you pass google.com in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of domain name, there are no built in utilities, no. You *can* get the name of a host (but not the domain name) by using `getCanonicalHostName()`  on [`InetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName%28%29) - that should work. The best answer here linked to the [DNS Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnsjava/) project, which will get you the domain name.

Example code to connect to, and get the host name from, one of Google's servers is given below:

```
public class GetHostName {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{74, 125,(byte) 227, 7});
    System.out.println(address.getCanonicalHostName());
}
}
```