# How to get client domain info?

Tags: java, spring, restlet

In a Spring or Restlet web application, how can I get the domain name of the client?

What I can do now is get client IP address only:

```
String clientIp = getRequest().getClientInfo().getAddress();
```

However I need to get the domain name of the client.

Mainly because I am making a `proxy` app which domains from `GoDaddy (for example)`:

- Forward `www CNAME` to the `proxy` app.
- Proxy app gets the domain name, say `xyz.com`, or `abc.com` and forward it to a specific IP or another domain.

Comment: What is a 'proxy app'? If you use apache http proxy so use proxy ajp instead. Other way edit your questin and add technologies and configuratins. The answer probably isn't belong java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general way, I suggest you have a look at the full content of the incoming request. Check the provided headers and see if they contain the data you need.

Uusing Restlet, you can have a look at the request#ClientInfo#UpStreamAddress method. It takes care of forwarding data provided by the request, and returns the client's IP.
I don't know what you mean by client's host domain.

Comment: I have two domains, say www.xyz.com and www.abc.com these two domain points to the same Restlet app. Now I need the app to determine or get if the client accessed xyz or abc. I mean this is the reason why I need to do this

Answer (score 5):

You can try with this.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(clientIp);
String host = addr.getHostName();
System.out.println(host);
```

[Converting an IP address to host name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554380/converting-an-ip-address-to-host-name)