# How to get URL from an IP address in Java?

Tags: java, url, networking

I found code to fetch host name from IP address. The code is some what like shown below:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
public class GetHostName{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        try{
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("74.125.68.94");
            System.out.println(host.getHostName());
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It shows output like:

```
sc-in-f94.1e100.net
```

But when i fired this IP address (74.125.68.94) through the browser it opens up Google website.
So my question is how can i fecth URL like http://www.google.com from an IP address rather than displaying **sc-in-f94.1e100.net** using java?

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You are using method to get host name and expecting to get URL.

Comment: yes i know, so i need to fetch url from ip address using java. Is any other method available?

Comment: No offence @user2004685 but its the exact opposite of that question.

Comment: I had tried this program it shows the IP address only @user2004685

Comment: Is there any other method? @CoderNeji

Comment: i am trying for it... As soon as i reach to it... i will post as an answer

Comment: Look at this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554380/converting-an-ip-address-to-host-name Specially the response from @SomeKittens

Comment: Its the same what i posted in question @user2004685

Comment: It says the same thing that `173.194.36.37` resolves to `bom04s02-in-f5.1e100.net` instead of `google.com` You won't figure it out until you see the Organization Name. https://ipinfo.io/173.194.36.37

Comment: it was helpful @user2004685

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that.

Usually, several domains can be reach on same IP. You can just identify the hostname like you already do. This is the name of the machine, equivalent to the IP, which serves the domain.

Moreover, an IP is just an address of a machine which also can serve any domain because it can be a web server or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing everything right. The thing is that today many host names can live on the same server. This way you can easily convert the host name to the IP address of the server but when you attempt to do the reverse, you only get the name of the server which is in this case `sc-in-f94.1e100.net`.

Here is an excerpt from [hcidata](http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.cgi):

> In the early years of the Internet, each sub-domain would have a unique IP address so it was common for a host machine to have only one sub domain name. Nowadays, the common practice is to have many sub-domains with the same IP address. It is also common for the domain name to be converted to the IP address of the host machine that runs the www sub domain.

I hope this will clear things up for you.